# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

this my code is and its showing this error "ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string." Please help me to solve this.

```
version: '2'
services:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    - ./letsencrypt-site:/usr/share/nginx/html
  networks:
    - docker-network
networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One must give a name to each service, and all of the service-specific configurations go under that name. See the [docker-compose v2 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#service-configuration-reference).

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  myservice:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./letsencrypt-site:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - docker-network
networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Great, if this solved your problem, you can click the green arrow to accept it.